# Translate and rotate transformation backward

Tags: rotation, transform

I'm applying translate and rotate transformation on an object in it own coordinate system.

Now I want to bring the object back to the initial position, with the same order of transformation. I mean, I know that if I apply env(rotate) and -translate I back in the initial position.

But which transformation should I apply to the original translate transformation in order to come back by applying the translate first transformation (as I understand the env(rotate) doesn't need to be changed)?

Answer (score 1):

Inverse of a rotation is transpose of the rotation matrix. And the inverse of a translation is the negative. With this in mind, if the object has rotated from position 0 to 1 to 2 to 3, you would need to apply inv(rot_23) and subtract transl_23, then rot_21-transl_21 and rot_10-trans_10 to come back from the rotated coordinate system to the initial coordinate system

Answer (score -1):

To bring an object back to its initial position after applying a rotation and translation transformation, you'll need to apply the inverse transformations in reverse order. Since you want to maintain the same order of transformations, here's what you should do:

1. First, apply the inverse of the translate transformation that brought the object to its final position. If the translation vector for the final position was (tx, ty), then you'll apply (-tx, -ty).
2. Then, apply the inverse of the rotate transformation that was applied to the object. To do this, you can apply the negative of the rotation angle or use the transpose of the rotation matrix if it's a matrix representation of the transformation.

By applying these inverse transformations in reverse order, you'll bring the object back to its initial position with the same order of transformations as before.

Comment: It's look like a ChatGPT answer.. that didn't understand the question.